# Jquery Chosen - autofill selected data on Load itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I have been using Jquery Chosen Plugin within my application.

I have 2 dropdowns within my page containig 
     Category   ---> normal Dropdown    ( contains All the Categories) 
     AttributeList  --> Chosen Dropdown    (contains All the Attributes)

Each Category has multiple Attributes Linked from the AttributeList.
Suppose we have 10 Categories and 40 Attributes.
Example CategoryA is linked to 4 Attributes (Attr1,Attr2,Attr3 and Attr4)

When we select CategoryA from Category Dropdown, the List (Attr1,Attr2,Attr3 and Attr4) should
be loaded in AttributeList Dropdown and will come as disabled from the 40 Attributes which gets displayed on clicking the chosen dropdown.

---

CateoryA --- Selected in Category DropDown

---

Attr1 X  Attr2 X  Attr3 X  Attr4 X    ---> AttributeList Chosen Dropdown

---

Attr1  --disabled
  Attr2  --disabled
  Attr3  --disabled
  Attr4  -- disabled
  Attr5 -- enabled state
  Attr39 -- enabled state
  Attr40  -- enabled state

---

How can we implement Autofill on page load/ Dropdown selection change for chosen dropdown.

Please help as I need to implement this As soon as possible.
At least help me in providing any documentation of chosen plugin.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? or post some code?

Answer (score 0):

My code is as under within cshtml Page
(a 'Category' dropdown and 'txtAttributes' is the chosen dropdown)
Currently it gets populated empty. But I need at least some of them should get populated on load itself based on logic.

### Within CSHTML Page

```
   <div class="row clear">
        <div class="span2">
            Category:</div>
        <div class="span8">
            <select id="Category" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="span2">
      Attributes:</div>
   <div class="span8">
    <select id="txtAttributes" style="display: none;" 
 data-placeholder="Select Attribute"  multiple="multiple" 
class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="-1"></select>
  </div>
```

### Javascript file contains

```
    $.ajax({
        url: cexPortal.getAbsoluteURL("CMS/Attribute/ListJson"),
        type: 'GET',
        data: '',
        success: function (data) {
            var AttributeList = data.List;

             $(document).data('AttributeList', AttributeList);

            $("#txtLinkAttributesToCategory").empty();

            $.each(AttributeList, function (i, data) {
                $("#txtAttributes").append("<option value=\"" + data.StructureId + "\">" + data.StructureName + "</option>");
            });

            var config = {
                '.chosen-select': {},
                '.chosen-select-deselect': {
                    allow_single_deselect: true
                },
                '.chosen-select-no-single': {
                    disable_search_threshold: 10
                },
                '.chosen-select-no-results': {
                    no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!'
                },
                '.chosen-select-width': {
                    width: "95%"
                }
            }
            $(document).data('ChosenConfig', config);

            for (var selector in config) {
                $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the chosen api dynamically select the value to chosen.

```
$('#kpiselect').val(["Attr1","Attr2","Attr3","Attr4"]).trigger("chosen:updated");
```